# How to find how much data size being used by each permissions of an Android App?

Tags: android, permissions

I got an Android application to develop, where I have to collect the Data Size being used by the each app as well as the permission requested by the app. Now I am asked to find the Data size used by each permission. i.e. For each permission, there are data collected..so how much data are collected by each permission..
Is this something doable & a valid question in Android ? Does Android provide these details ? Please Help

Comment: I don't think there is relation between android permission and data size e.g. if you ask for camera permission android system handles it with system dialog and stores it which I think should be a flag so there is no data size associated with it

Comment: Thanks Manoj for clarifying this to me. It'll help me to make my client understand  this.

Comment: welcome Rupesh :)